# Using Apache Camel in a web application without using Spring?

Tags: apache-camel

I am exploring the usage of Apache Camel in a web application to do a few integration patterns.

The only examples that i find are using Spring.

Are there samples available without using Spring?

Appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party but wanted to post an updated response. I recently created a featherweight framework called **Harness** that makes it super easy to create web services in Camel *without* any Spring dependencies. It comes with several nifty features including:

- plug-and-play insertion of Camel objects into a 'Harness' that provides boiler-plate code required for route creation, registry management, and testing.
- the ability to rapidly create new business logic with very little code. This because between Camel and Harness most of what you might need is already provided.
- the benefit of implementing an IoC framework like Guice w/o the bloat of using an IoC framework like Guice. Through the use of *.properties files the app can inject mocks, different processors, and even re-wire the business logic.
- a means of reconfiguring, removing, or even adding business logic without shutting down the app or impacting anything else the app might be doing.

The framework core library can be found [here](https://github.com/davidholiday/camel-harness-lib). This is where the Harness files are along with some helper ultilities.

The reference implementation an be found [here](https://github.com/davidholiday/camel-harness). This is a fully functional Camel microservice that can serve as a template for getting your Camel ride to where it needs to go.

*UPDATE JUL'23*

A while back I wrote a different Camel Microservice framework called k-car. The source is [here](https://github.com/davidholiday/kcar). This one is less complex than the previous version and uses Velocity and Maven to create components and services from templates.

Comment: [According to JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5906) and [the official documentation](http://camel.apache.org/servletlistener-component.html), this feature already exists in native Camel, which would make needing third-party libraries to accomplish this less necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Spring is often used to sort of hold the Camel context as a bean.

Feel free to use Camel like in any other member of a managed bean. It might be a bit tricker than using spring depending on what architecture you have in your webapp.

Typically, you create or reuse some singleton bean inside your webapp (there are different ways to do that, such as `@Singleton` EJB, or some DI framework such as GUICE (and spring..). 
Then just create an instance variable with the camel context such CamelContext ctx; then in construcutor/singleton constructor, ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();

You now have camel running, just keep adding components and routes to it using Java DSL. There are several components of Camel that are semi dependent of Spring anyway. Such as JMS component, Spring-WS and others. Also, you might have a tricky time to jack Camel into the servlet container without spring. But it depends on the use case you have for it.

Read about the context lifecycle here 
http://camel.apache.org/lifecycle.html

Answer (score 1):

I have wanted to add support for this for a while now. But never got around doing it, or log a ticket. So today I logged a ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5906 so eventually in the future we have a way of using a serlvet listener to bootstrap Camel. More details on the ticket.

Comment: I have added such a new component, which will be part of Camel 2.11. There is also a new example: camel-example-servlet-tomcat-no-spring to showcase this as well. Working on adding docs now.

Comment: Link to the example on github: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-servlet-tomcat-no-spring

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you should create a listener class `MyCamelContextInitialisingListener` that implements `javax.servlet.ServletContextListener` - this will contain the Camel initialisation logic.

You register the listener in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.cheese.MyCamelContextInitialisingListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<web-app>
```

The listener will contain something along the lines of:

```
private CamelContext camelContext;

@Override 
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    camelContext.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());
    camelContext.start();
}

@Override 
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    camelContext.stop()
}
```

The class `MyRouteBuilder` would be a `RouteBuilder` implementation that you define, that uses the Camel Java DSL to define routing logic.

No Spring needed.

Answer (score 1):

Very Easy just do the following:

```
<display-name>My Web Application</display-name>



<!-- you can configure any of the properties on CamelContext, eg setName will be configured as below -->



    <context-param>
        <param-name>name</param-name>
        <param-value>MyCamel</param-value>
      </context-param>

  <!-- location of Camel route xml files -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>routeBuilder-MyRoute</param-name>
    <!-- define the routes as a resource from the classpath by prefixing the value with classpath: -->
    <!-- note: instead of using a XML file we can also define the routes in Java code in a RouteBuilder class -->
    <param-value>classpath:camel-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- the listener that kick-starts Camel -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.camel.component.servletlistener.CamelServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Camel servlet used in the Camel application -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Comment: You should give a disclaimer when you copy paste code examples from other places - right now it looks like you are trying to claim this is your work. [code](http://camel.apache.org/servlet-tomcat-no-spring-example.html)

Comment: sure my bad, forgot the source,next time i will link the source.thanks for the heads up